# Google check Out Use

Tags: gwt, google-checkout

I am a student doing a dissertation on GWT. I want to include google checkout in my application. Do i need to have bank account or similar issues to include, how can i proceed??

Answer (score 0):

For demonstration and/or testing purposes you can use the Google Checkout "sandbox environment".

The sandbox simulates transactions using "test" credit card numbers and offers the exact same functionality as the production Google Checkout system, except no money is involved. No bank account is required as these are not transactions involving real charges.

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Sandbox.html
https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=134469